# Eloquent Make a long query

Tags: mysql, laravel, class, phpmyadmin, eloquent

How do I make an Eloquent query with more than one where statement and orderby 2 types and have it paginated or limited?

```
PostIco::table('posts')
    ->where('listingType', '!=', 1)
    ->OrderBy('listingType', 'created_at')
    ->limit(25)
    ->paginate(10)
```

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `PostIco` an eloquent model? If so, you don't use `table` method on it.

```
PostIco::where('listingType', '!=', 1)
    // Instead of OrderBy
    ->orderBy('listingType', 'asc')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->limit(25)
    ->paginate(10);
```

You can also do it with `DB` facade:

```
DB::table('posts')
    ->where('listingType', '!=', 1)
    ->orderBy('listingType', 'asc')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->limit(25)
    ->paginate(10);
```

EDIT: corrected orderBy statements

Answer (score 1):

for multiple where clauses you can do:

```
PostIco::where('listingType', '!=', 1)->where('status', 1) // and you can add chain of wheres
->orderBy('listingType')
->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
->limit(25)
->paginate(10);
// OR

PostIco::where('listingType', '!=', 1)->orWhere('status', 1) // and you can add chain of wheres and orWheres
->orderBy('listingType', 'asc')
->limit(25)
->paginate(10);
```